# Android UIAUTOMATOR Testing?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

Hi guys I am testing my app UI. I applied monkey runner test. But I want to test it with another framework as well. Can anybody tell me that we can use uiautomatorviewer and uiautomator testing method to test API below then 16 like Android 3.0 and below versions?
or please recommend me some other testing method by which I can test my UI on all  versions of the android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uiautomator framework works only with API level 16 and above, therefore you cannot use UIautomator framework to test devices with API level <16.

Following are few other frameworks which work across all the versions/api levels

1.[MonkeyRunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html)

2.[Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/)

Answer (score 0):

The most recommended tool for testing android application are

1.[Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/)

2.[Espresso](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso)

3.[Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/)

4.[Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/)

Happy Testing